# Finding a basis of a vector space of polynomials of n degree

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $c_0, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ be distinct reals. For $i \in \{ 0, \dots , n\}$ define 
\begin{align*}
f_i(x) := \prod_{k=0, k\neq i}^n \frac{x-c_k}{c_i-c_k}.
\end{align*}
Prove that $\beta := (f_0, f_1, \ldots,f_n)$ is a basis of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ and hence write an arbitrary polynomial $g\in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ as a unique linear combination of the elements in $\beta$.

Give me some hints so that I can start this sum. Please help.

Comment: What are the $x_i$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_i(x)=\prod_{k=0,k \neq i}^{n} \frac{(x-c_k)}{(c_i-c_k)}
\end{eqnarray*}
then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} g(c_k)f_k(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

For the linearly indepence of the (Lagrange polynomials) $f_i$, start with the usual assumption and then consider evaluating at the given $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now for finding an explicit expression for writing any polynomial as a linear combination of the $f_i$, here is what I have in mind for this.
Define for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ an element $\text{ev}_{c} \in (P_n(\mathbb{R}))^{\vee}$ (that is the dual space of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$) by $\text{ev}_c(p):=p(c)$.
Then (show that) $(\text{ev}_{c_0}, \dots , \text{ev}_{c_n})$ is a basis for $(P_n(\mathbb{R}))^{\vee}$ (use the standard basis for $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ and then find a Vandermonde matrix ;-)).

Now you finally have to notice that the basis $(f_0, \dots, f_n)$ is indeed dual to the basis $(\text{ev}_{c_0}, \dots , \text{ev}_{c_n})$.

It almost immediately follows how you can express any polynomial in terms of the Lagrange polynomials. (Hint for this: Write your polynomial $g$ as a linear combination of the Lagrange polynomials and then find out what $g(c_i)$ is.)